# Auction project: C++ error with cin

Tags: c++, iostream, cout, getline, cin

I am working on project that is suppose to replicate an auction. I am suppose to ask for the first bidder's name and if the bidder's name is left black give an error message saying BidderID left blank.

### Problem

The code keeps on automatically skipping the cin after asking for "Bidder1 ID" and going straight to the error message of error: bidder ID blank. I am using a function I created called getName, which I figured is the problem but other places used in the code it is acting properly.

```
int main()
{
    double bid1, bid2;//declare bid1, bid2

    printHeader();

    string lotName= getName("Enter lot name: "); //lot name
    double reservePrice= getPrice("Reserve price: $");
    if (reservePrice<=0) {
        printErrorMessage(5);
        return 0;
    }

    cout<<"\n";

    string bidder1= getName("Bidder 1 ID: "); //bidder1 name


    if (bidder1== "") {
        printErrorMessage(3);
        bid1=0;
    }

    else {
        bid1= getPrice("Bidder1 price: $"); //bidder 1 price
        bool lead= isBidPriceGood (bid1, reservePrice); //true if bid1>reservePrice
        if (lead==true)
            cout<<"\n"<<bidder1<<" is high bidder, current price = $"<<bid1<<endl<<endl;
    }

    string bidder2= getName("Bidder 2 ID: "); //bidder2 name

    getline(cin,bidder2);

    if (bidder2== "") {
        printErrorMessage(3);
        bid2=0;
    }
    else {
        bid2= getPrice("Bidder1 price: $"); //bidder 2 price
        isBidPriceGood (bid2, reservePrice); //true if bid2>reservePrice
    }

    //function

    string getName(string prompt)
    {
        string name;
        cout<<prompt;
        getline(cin,name);
        return name;
    }




    double getPrice(string prompt)
    {
        string x;
        double price;
        cout<< prompt;
        cin>>price;
        getline(cin,x);
        return price;
    }

    void printErrorMessage(int num)
    {
        if (num == 1) {
            cout << endl
                << "  ERROR: Reserve not met, bid rejected" << endl << endl;
        } else if (num == 2) {
            cout << endl
                << "  ERROR: Negative price, bid rejected" << endl << endl;
        } else if (num == 3) {
            cout << endl
                << "  ERROR: Blank bidder ID, no bid allowed" << endl << endl;
        } else if (num == 4) {
            cout << endl
                << "ERROR: Neither bidder met Reserve, auction canceled" << endl << endl;
        } else if (num == 5) {
            cout << endl
                << "ERROR: Reserve is not positive, auction canceled" << endl << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "   This should never print" << endl << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: homework? (this is just a filler because SO doesn't allow short comments)

Answer (score 1):

`getline(cin,name)` will read until the next newline. Probably you already have a newline waiting in the input-stream, from some previous input where you didn't read in the newline. For example, your `cin>>price` will read in a number, but won't read in a newline after that number, so if a call to `getName` is preceded by a call to `getPrice`, then the newline after the price will still be waiting, and `getName` will see it as the end of the line.

---

**Edited for updated question:** You need to change this:

```
string bidder2= getName("Bidder 2 ID: "); //bidder2 name

getline(cin,bidder2);
```

to just this:

```
string bidder2= getName("Bidder 2 ID: "); //bidder2 name
```

Do you see why?

Comment: Thanks for the help. So how should I get the getline function to read a newline before it hits the next getline

Comment: @user1188766: Since you're expecting the user to give the price on its own line, you can have `getPrice` call `getline` after it gets the price. (As a sanity-check, you can make sure that the result of `getline` is an empty string, or at least a string of just whitespace.) That will swallow the newline for you. (There are other ways, but I think this is the simplest for what you need.)

Comment: How should I get rid of the newline waiting in the input-stream before

Comment: @user1188766: I don't understand. Do you, for some reason, not want to modify `getPrice`?

Comment: Now if I leave first Bidder1 ID blank or first getline blank, the next get line needs two enters to move on to next line of code.

Comment: @user1188766: `getline` will never require more than one newline. Could you update your question to clarify how your code currently looks, and what behavior you're currently seeing?

Comment: int main()
{
 double bid1, bid2;//declare bid1, bid2
   
    printHeader();
    
    string lotName= getName("Enter lot name: "); //lot name
    double reservePrice= getPrice("Reserve price: $");
    if (reservePrice<=0) {
        printErrorMessage(5);
        return 0;
    }
    
    cout<<"\n";
    
    string bidder1= getName("Bidder 1 ID: "); //bidder1 name
    
    
    if (bidder1== "") {
        printErrorMessage(3);
        bid1=0;
    }

Comment: At times for cin it is requiring two enters to move on with the rest of the code

Comment: Added a getline call to the getprice function